# Azure event hubs metrics not appearing when deploying with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-eventhub

When deploying with some other components (of a data pipeline) like function app and cosmosdb, metrics graphs on azure event hubs portal are not appearing instead graphs show "Resource not found"[image: event hubs on azure portal].
But when I deploy the same terraform code for event hubs namespace without other components, metric graphs appears. Here is terraform code:

```
locals {
  ip_rule_map = flatten([
    for cidr in ["182.191.83.208"] : [
      {
        action  = "Allow"
        ip_mask = cidr
      }
    ]
  ])
}
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "avro-ingestion" {
  name                = "test-eh"
  location            = "Central US"
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 1

  network_rulesets = false ? [{
    default_action                 = "Deny"
    ip_rule                        = local.ip_rule_map
    virtual_network_rule           = []
    trusted_service_access_enabled = true
    }] : [
    {
      default_action                 = "Allow"
      ip_rule                        = local.ip_rule_map
      virtual_network_rule           = []
      trusted_service_access_enabled = true
    }
  ]



  tags = {
    Name      = "avro-ingestion"
    Purpose   = "data-ingestion-infra-deployment"
    CreatedBy = "emumba"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule" "user_managed" {
  name                = "UserManagedSharedAccessKey"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.avro-ingestion.name
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"

  listen = true
  send   = true
  manage = true
}
resource "null_resource" "schema-registry" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_eventhub_namespace.avro-ingestion
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command     = "az eventhubs namespace schema-registry create --name test-schema-group  --namespace-name test-eh --resource-group test-rg --schema-compatibility Backward --schema-type Avro"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub" "thunder" {
  name                = "test"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.avro-ingestion.name
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1

}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group" "function-app-cg" {
  name                = "fApp-cons-group"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.avro-ingestion.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.thunder.name
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"
}
```

main.tf file where I am calling all modules along with event hubs namespace module:

```
resource "random_string" "random_Sacc1" {
  length      = 4
  special     = false
  upper       = false
  min_lower   = 1
  min_numeric = 1
}

resource "random_string" "random_Sacc2" {
  length      = 2
  special     = false
  upper       = false
  min_lower   = 1
  min_numeric = 1
}

module "azure-resource-group" {
  source = "../../modules/resource-group"

  region         = var.region
  res_group_name = var.res_group_name
}

module "azure-virtual-network" {
  depends_on = [
    module.azure-resource-group
  ]
  source = "../../modules/virtual-network"

  rg_name               = module.azure-resource-group.name
  rg_location           = module.azure-resource-group.location
  vn_name               = var.vn_name
  vn_cidrs              = var.vn_cidrs
  subnets               = var.subnets
  subnet_cidrs          = var.subnet_cidrs
  pub_nsg_name          = var.pub_nsg_name
  private_nsg_name      = var.private_nsg_name
  internet_ip_cidr_list = var.internet_ip_cidr_list

}


module "azure-ad-app-registration" {
  depends_on = [
    module.azure-resource-group
  ]
  source = "../../modules/app-role-assignment"

  app-display-name = var.app-display-name
  rg_name          = module.azure-resource-group.name
}


module "azure-eventhubs" {
  source                = "../../modules/event-hubs"
  ns_name               = var.eventhub_namespace_name
  eventhub_name         = var.eventhub_name
  cons_group_name       = var.cons_group_name
  rg_name               = module.azure-resource-group.name
  rg_location           = module.azure-resource-group.location
  enable_private_access = var.enable_private_access
  cidr_list             = var.public_cidr_list
  vnet_id_dns           = module.azure-virtual-network.vnet-id
  private_ep_subnet     = module.azure-virtual-network.private-subent1-id
  dns_zone_name         = var.dns_zone_name_private_ep
  schema_group_name = var.eventhub_schema_group_name
}

module "azure-storage-account" {
  depends_on = [
  module.azure-virtual-network
  ]
  source = "../../modules/storage-account"

  storage_acc_name      = "${var.storage_acc_name}${random_string.random_Sacc1.id}"
  rg_name               = module.azure-resource-group.name
  rg_location           = module.azure-resource-group.location
  enable_private_access = var.enable_private_access
  cidr_list             = var.public_cidr_list
  vnet_id_dns           = module.azure-virtual-network.vnet-id
  private_ep_subnet     = module.azure-virtual-network.private-subent1-id
  dns_zone_name         = var.dns_zone_name_private_ep

}


module "azure-cosmos-db" {
  source = "../../modules/cosmos-db"

  acc_name                 = var.cosmos_acc_name
  db_name                  = var.cosmos_db_name
  rg_name                  = module.azure-resource-group.name
  rg_location              = module.azure-resource-group.location
  cosmos_db_container_name = var.cosmos_db_container_name
  enable_private_access    = var.enable_private_access
  cidr_list                = var.public_cidr_list
  vnet_id_dns              = module.azure-virtual-network.vnet-id
  private_ep_subnet        = module.azure-virtual-network.private-subent1-id
  dns_zone_name            = var.dns_zone_name_private_ep
  synapse_link = var.enable_synapse_link
}


# module "fApp-azure-storage-account" {
#   source = "../../modules/storage-account"

#   storage_acc_name      = "${var.storage_acc_fApp_name}${random_string.random_Sacc2.id}"
#   rg_name               = module.azure-resource-group.name
#   rg_location           = module.azure-resource-group.location
#   enable_private_access = var.enable_private_access
#   cidr_list             = var.public_cidr_list
#   private_ep_subnet     = element(module.azure-virtual-network.subnet_id_list, 1)
#   dns_zone_name         = var.dns_zone_name_private_ep

# }


module "data-ingestion-fApp" {
  depends_on = [
    module.azure-cosmos-db,
    module.azure-eventhubs,
    module.azure-storage-account
  ]
  source = "../../modules/function-app"

  rg_name                  = module.azure-resource-group.name
  rg_location              = module.azure-resource-group.location
  application_insight_name = var.application_insight_name
  fApp_service_plan_name   = var.fApp_service_plan_name
  fApp_name                = var.fApp_name
  fApp-storage_acc_name    = "${var.storage_acc_fApp_name}${random_string.random_Sacc2.id}"
  enable_private_access    = var.enable_private_access
  vnet_id_dns              = module.azure-virtual-network.vnet-id
  private_ep_subnet        = module.azure-virtual-network.private-subent1-id
  integration_vnet_name    = module.azure-virtual-network.vnet-name
  integration_subnet_name  = module.azure-virtual-network.private-subent2-name
  func_configurations = { "AZURE_CLIENT_ID" = module.azure-ad-app-registration.client_id
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"                = module.azure-ad-app-registration.client_secret,
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID"                    = module.azure-ad-app-registration.tenant_id,
    "EVENTHUB_NAME"                      = var.eventhub_name,
    "EVENTHUB_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAMESPACE" = "${var.eventhub_namespace_name}.servicebus.windows.net",
    "SCHEMA_GROUP_NAME"                  = var.eventhub_schema_group_name,
    "OUTPUT_CONTAINER"                   = var.storage_acc_container_name,
    "OUTPUT_PATH"                        = var.storage_acc_container_path,
    "COSMOS_DB_URI"                      = module.azure-cosmos-db.cosmos_account_uri,
    "COSMOS_DB_PRIMARY_KEY"              = module.azure-cosmos-db.cosmos_account_primary_key,
    "COSMOS_DB_NAME"                     = var.cosmos_db_name,
    "COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_NAME"           = var.cosmos_db_container_name,
    "a10devops_namespace_connection"     = module.azure-eventhubs.eventhub_conn_str,
  "a10devops_storage_connection" = module.azure-storage-account.storage_account_conn_str }
}
```

Comment: The local variables block is not pasted correctly. Also, what does "When deploying same configurations separately everything works fine" mean?

Comment: I am deploying a data pipeline on azure using terraform. It includes Event hub namespace, function app, cosmos db and storage account. When I say deploying same configurations seperately, it means that I am running the same terraform code for event hubs namespace but separate from the rest of the component's code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's connected/separated? Are you using modules or it's all in one terraform file? Are there any references to the other resources you mention?

Comment: Yes, I have written modules for every component and calling them in one main.tf file. Adding the code where I am calling these modules in my question.

Comment: Great, so another question: have you defined the outputs in the respective modules? For example, where is this `module.azure-resource-group.name` coming from?

Comment: Yes, all the outputs I am using are defined in modules. I have verified it. Its working. 
```module.azure-resource-group.name``` is an output defined in ```azure-resource-group``` module. 

```output "name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.a10-data-ingestion.name
}```

Comment: Ok, when I look at the eventhub code, I see that you're setting the resource group name to `test-rg` and then during the module call there is a variable `rg_name` which is set to the output of the resource group module.

Comment: @MarkoE In the event hub code I have hard coded the values to test its working when deploying stand alone. This is the same code which in written in module. Only values are hard coded.